# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS backup failed

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Hi I am a new user so be gentle! I have been getting on really well with Ubuntu since escaping from MS, but have encountered a problem with a scheduled backup, using Déjà Dup Backup Tool and a failed manual backup as per:

```
Invalid data - SHA1 hash mismatch for file:
 duplicity-inc.20190328T075552Z.to.20190404T071308Z.vol1.difftar.gz
 Calculated hash: d352faac0f1c007d0552e29be9b404ced5b500a8
 Manifest hash: 8219e5f0e5305867f26a91a0b02b490420bed7cb
```

I have had no other problems to date, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**NB**. since I asked my question, (having previously searched and not found any information), I was able to follow a link for related subject which was very useful. As a result I am in  the process of looking at alternatives, as it seems that there are quite a few issues with the current backup program. 
If I get something to work better, without being a nightmare set up I will let you know.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Time for an update!
I had a look around the web for useful tools that would help protect data on my machine, and have been using Timeshift successfully for some time. I'm afraid life has got in the way of finding anything else to try. At least it provides a measure of comfort-false or otherwise! Not quite the same as the tools that the system that I escaped from offers but hey... better to be free!
Thanks for the help.
Cheers.